# Android Navigation Drawer not opening up new Activity

Tags: java, android

I have created a Navigation drawer and for some reason When I select an item from it it does not open up the new activity I am not sure what the problem is thats why I am asking for any help or guidance. I have created this in previous projects but I cannot seem to find out the problem. when I click any of the items on the menu nothing happens. I have added a log too to check if the event gets fired but I dont think it is being triggered.

```
    public class DashBoard extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, 
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference();
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        displayMessage();
        final String userID = mAuth.getUid();
        assert userID != null;
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userID);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user != null) {
                    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
                    TextView navUsername = headerView.findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawerName);
                    navUsername.setText(user.getUserName());
                    final CircleImageView navProfilePicture = headerView.findViewById(R.id.navPicture);
                    storageReference.child(user.getmImageUrl()).getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                            navProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(DashBoard.this, "Error Occurred: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.logOut) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogIn.class));
        }
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint({"WrongConstant", "NonConstantResourceId"})
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.pp:
                Toast.makeText(DashBoard.this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(DashBoard.this, PersonalProfile.class));
                break;
            case R.id.chat:
                startActivity(new Intent(DashBoard.this, ChatRoom.class));
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
        return true;
    }
}

This is the drawer menu xml class where I create different menu items and reference their ids in the switch statement
drawer_menu.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/pp"
            android:title="Personal Profile" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/chat"
            android:title="Chat" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/users"
            android:title="All users" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/maps"
            android:title="Nearby Users"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: when you'r clicking on pp the "Test" toast message showing up?

Comment: Hi @RajendraMahato The toast message was being used as a test to see if the click listener was working it was not. I was able to solve this problem as it was due to a problem in the xml file I had the navigation drawer in the wrong tag thanks for your help!

Comment: i was thinking the same, i wanted to see if click listener is working or not, this how we debug step by step. Its Working then great. happy coding